# Problem with tracking

Tags: objects, tracking, axis

When i'm trying to set origin, floor, X axis and Y axis my object just flips 90 degrees:

[image]

Comment: Now it just flipped upside down

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you would like to do. Could you rephrase it? Something like: 'I'm trying to XXX, but I can't, because YYY'?